# Output of Reduce + Simplify

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I'm using Reduce to solve some equations and then simplify to eliminate some undesired results. The problem is that, when I apply Simplify, it messes with my output from reduce. 
As an example:

```
    eq = Cos[x] + Sin[x] == y
    Reduce[eq, x]
    Simplify[Reduce[eq, x]]
```

My outputs are

```
    (C[1] \[Element] Integers && y == -1 && (x == -(\[Pi]/2) + 2 \[Pi] C[1] || x == \[Pi] + 2 \[Pi] C[1])) || (C[1] \[Element] Integers && 1 + y != 0 && (x == 2 ArcTan[(1 - Sqrt[2 - y^2])/(1 + y)] + 2 \[Pi] C[1] ||x == 2 ArcTan[(1 + Sqrt[2 - y^2])/(1 + y)] + 2 \[Pi] C[1]))
```

And with Simplify:

```
    (C[1] \[Element] Integers && y == -1 && (\[Pi] + 2 x == 4 \[Pi] C[1] || \[Pi] + 2 \[Pi] C[1] ==x)) || (C[1] \[Element] Integers && 1 + y != 0 && (x == 2 (ArcTan[(1 - Sqrt[2 - y^2])/(1 + y)] + \[Pi] C[1]) || x == 2 (ArcTan[(1 + Sqrt[2 - y^2])/(1 + y)] + \[Pi] C[1])))
```

Of course, Simplify here is not necessary, but my real equations are rather long to put here. My point is, when I use simplify, I get x to the lhs, so I can't use ToRules to make a list of rules from my output. I sounds like a silly question, but I've tried a lot of different things and I cant figure it out how to do it...

Thank you so much

Comment: I can make it work for some cases: ToRules[x - a == 
   b + c + d] /. ((x + lhs_) -> rhs_) :> (x -> (-lhs + rhs)) will produce the desired result, but if my lhs is (-x+a) it won't work...

Comment: Sometimes you get `x==complicated` and you would like `x==simple` but `Simplify thinks the result is simpler if it pushes things across the `==`. For those cases try `x==complicated/.Equal[left_,right_]:>Equal[Simplify[left],Simplify[right]]` For `x+complicated==morecomplicated` try `x+complicated==morecomplicated /.Equal[left_,right_]:>Solve[Equal[left,right],x]` or even replace that `Solve` with `Reduce` and see if that works for you. If you can show more specific examples that still don't work then perhaps someone can show a general method that works for you.

Comment: Well, it's working so far. I'll try to come with a more general method if someone comes with the same issue. Thank you!